# MySQL service error

Tags: mysql

So I keep getting alerted to my mysql service getting restarted. I check the logs and I find this:

```
[ERROR] mysqld: Table './mysql/gtid_slave_pos' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
[ERROR] mysqld: Table 'gtid_slave_pos' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
[ERROR] mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
[ERROR] mysql.user: 1 client is using or hasn't closed the table properly
```

but looking at the health of the table using `CHECK TABLE`, it shows OK. Are there any other things I can check? the query history is disabled, so I can't really check it for *for now*. Any help would be appreciated. I am willing to tell other information as much as I can.